# freetds installed in my centos, how to use this driver with in php

Tags: php, sql-server, centos, freetds

FreeTDS has been installed on my Linux server, and I can connect to MSSQL Server from with in console using "tsql"

Now my requirement is to use this driver in PHP to connect to a remote SQL Server,

What configuration i need to do on my Centos Server

cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)

Thanks in advance

Comment: when "phpinfo" there is no line stating mssql
# php --info |grep  "mssql"

PWD => /home/cpeasyapache/src/php-5.4.35/ext/mssql
_SERVER["PWD"] => /home/cpeasyapache/src/php-5.4.35/ext/mssql
_ENV["PWD"] => /home/cpeasyapache/src/php-5.4.35/ext/mssql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to install the mssql and/or the pdo_dblib PHP extensions.  You should be able to use your package manager to install them.

Comment: how can i install pdo_dblib PHP can u please guide, is this possible from cPanel UI?